# Canopy: Changing the way auto-completion works

Tags: python, autocomplete, enthought

I want to be able to customize auto-completion in canopy, so it behaves like sublime.

Is it possible? And if so, where do i find the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Canopy currently doesn't expose the API to customize auto-completion.

But, what exactly do you mean by making it behave like sublime?

Comment: i mean customize it such that the auto completions of canopy acts like sublime. where when you type `cla` sublime gives you the complete structure of a class. i don't want to use macros